# How to use 2 different selects depending on an item value?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm new to PL/SQL and Oracle. Is there a way to do 2 different selects, depending on the value of an APEX item?

For example:

```
IF :item IS NULL
    THEN select abc from d where row1 = 2
ELSE
    select zzz from b where row2 = 2
```

Is there a simple way to do this just using Oracle SQL and not even using PL/SQL?

Comment: Can you  try using  UNION statement
Select abc [ValueColumn] From d Where row1= 2
UNION
Select zzz [ValueColumn] From b Where row2= 2

Comment: It depends on how many rows and columns your *select* statements returns. Can you give a little more context?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the LOV source as PL/SQL that returns a string:

```
DECLARE
   lov VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
   IF :item IS NULL THEN
      lov := 'select abc from d where row1 = 2';
   ELSE
      lov := 'select zzz from b where row2 = 2';
   END IF;
   RETURN lov;
END;
```